# How to select objects based on materials?

Tags: selection-tools

Is it possible to select all objects that have a particular material assigned to them?

E.g. if I have many objects that use the same material and I want to select them for *Copy to Selected*, how can I do this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

*Object mode:*
*Select > Select linked > Material* or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> > *Material*.

*Edit mode:* Select face that has the material applied to:
*Select > Select Similar > Material*
or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> > *Material*

[image]

Answer (score 5):

1. Download the [Material Utilities](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Materials_Utils) addon
2. Select all objects with <kbd>A</kbd>
3. Access Material Utilities <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>. Select "*Select by Material*".
4. Choose the material you want to select by

Comment: Thank you very useful in my case where I need to find materials that I want to delete and I don't know where are applied, cause I have appended object from another file.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be this:

1. in the Outliner set "Display Mode" to "Blender File" ( in the top, the dropdown menu next to the "Editor Type" dropdown)
2. there should be a list with all materials (in the top is search bar)
3. right-click on the material and select "Select Linked" from the context menu (Be aware that hidden Objects will not be selected)